# open particular drop down menu on click of child element for small device

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am creating responsive menu using jquery and css3. here is my `jQuery`

```
var ico = $('<span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span>');
          $('nav#nav li:has(ul)').append(ico);

          $('span.fa-caret-right').on('click',function(){
            $('nav#nav li:has(ul)').toggleClass('open');
          });

          $('a#toggle').on('click',function(e){
            $('html').toggleClass('open-menu');
            return false;
          });


          $('div#overlay').on('click',function(){
            $('html').removeClass('open-menu');
          })
```

as you can see in the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/464dzhno/2/), when i click on the icon of "what we do",
both submenu are opening.

i want to open one particular at a time and close it when click on other submenu parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey this code will help you.

```js
    $('nav#nav li:has(ul)').append("<span class='fa fa-caret-right'></span>");
      
      var icon = $('span.fa-caret-right');
    
    $('span.fa-caret-right').on('click',function() {
           if($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
               icon.parent().removeClass('open');
           } else {
               icon.parent().removeClass('open');
            $(this).parent().addClass('open');
           }
    });
    
    $('a#toggle').on('click',function(e){
   $('html').toggleClass('open-menu');
   return false;
    });
    
    
    $('div#overlay').on('click',function(){
   $('html').removeClass('open-menu');
    })
```

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
a { outline:none; cursor:pointer; text-decoration: none; }

nav{
 display:block;
}

/*** Navigation Menu :: Start***/
#nav {
 margin: 30px 0 0;
 float: left;
}
#nav ul li {
 float: left;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-left: 5px;
}
#nav ul li a {
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #2d2d2d;
 padding: 8px 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 display: block;
}
#nav ul li a:hover,
#nav ul li.active a,
#nav ul li.quote a,
#nav ul li:hover a {
 background: #EF3E36;
 color: #fff;
}
a#toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
}
a#toggle span {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#nav {
  text-align: center;
  transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
}
#nav a { color: white; }
#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(22,160,133, 0.8);
}
#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
#nav ul li a span {
  margin-left: 15px;
  transition: all ease-out 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-out 0.1s;
  display: none;
}
#nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  width: 215px;
  text-align: left;
}
#nav ul li ul li { display: block; }
#nav ul li ul li a { display: block; }
#nav ul li:hover a span { transform: rotateZ(90deg); }
#nav ul li:hover ul { display: block; }

#nav ul li ul.sub-menu {
 position: absolute;
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 display: none;
 z-index: 999999;
 top: 100%;
}
#nav ul li ul:before {
 border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-left: 11px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 11px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 23px;
    top: -10px;
}
#nav ul li ul:after {
 border-bottom: 9px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 24px;
    top: -9px;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul.sub-menu {
 display: block;
}
#nav ul li ul.sub-menu li {
 float: none;
 padding: 0;
}
#nav ul li ul.sub-menu li:first-child {
 border-top: none;
}
#nav ul li ul.sub-menu li a {
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #3a3a3a;
 border-radius: 0;
 text-transform: capitalize;
 padding: 6px 3px;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul.sub-menu li a {
 background: none;
}
#nav ul li ul.sub-menu li a:hover,
#nav ul li ul.sub-menu li.active a {
 color: #ef3e36;
 background: none;
}

/******* Media Queries *******/
@media (max-width: 1366px) {
 html, body {
  height: 100%;
 }
 html.open-menu body {
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 
 #nav ul li ul.sub-menu li {
  border-top: 1px solid #5a607c;
  border-bottom: none;
 }
 #nav ul li ul.sub-menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 3px;
 }
 #nav ul li ul.sub-menu li a:hover, #nav ul li ul.sub-menu li.active a {
  color: #fff;
 }
 
 
 /* Responsive Nav */
 html.open-menu a#toggle {
 transform: translateX(0px);
 -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
 background: black;
 }
  html.open-menu #wrapper {
  transform: translateX(250px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
 }
 #wrapper {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
  height: 100%;
 }
 a#toggle { display: block; }
 #nav {
   position: fixed;
   width: 250px;
   height: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
   top: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   overflow-y: auto;
   background-color: #20222B;
   transform: translateX(-250px);
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-250px);
   box-shadow: -1px -4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
   -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
   margin: 0;
   left: 0;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s;
   z-index: -5;
 }
 #nav ul {
   text-align: left;
   background-color: transparent;
 }
 #nav ul li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
 }
 #nav ul li { display: block; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; border-top: 1px solid #5A607C; }
 #nav ul li a { display: block; color: #FFF; border-radius: 0; padding: 13px 10px; }
 #nav ul li a span { float: right; }
 #nav ul li ul.sub-menu {
   position: static;
   width: auto;
   background: none;
   border-radius: 0;
   box-shadow: none;
 }
 #nav ul li:hover ul.sub-menu {
  display: none;
 }
 #nav ul li ul:before,
 #nav ul li ul:after {
  display: none;
 }
 #nav ul li:hover a span { 
  transform: rotateZ(0); 
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0); 
 }
 #nav ul li.open a {  }
 #nav ul li.open span { 
  /*transform: rotateZ(90deg); 
  border-left: none; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5a607c; */
  background: url("../images/caret_open.png") center center no-repeat;
 }
 #nav ul li.open ul.sub-menu { display: block; background: #4D5166; animation-duration: 0s !important; }
 #nav ul li a:hover, #nav ul li.active a, #nav ul li.quote a {
  background: none;
  color: #FFF;
 }
 #nav ul li span {  
  background: url("../images/caret_arrow.png") center center no-repeat;
  display: block;
        color: white;
  height: 11px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 16px 17px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 1px solid #5a607c;
  z-index: 3;
 }
 #nav ul li:hover a {
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
 }
 html.open-menu { overflow: hidden; max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; }
 html.open-menu div#overlay {
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
   width: calc(-150%);
   left: 250px;
 }
 html.open-menu nav#nav {
   z-index: 5; 
 }
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="wrapper">
<a id="toggle" href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="fa fa-bars"></span></a>
<nav id="nav">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="index">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="what_we_do">what we do</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#">submenu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">submenu item</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="about">about us</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#">submenu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">submenu item</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: After a long long time, got exactly what i wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

Here use this below code:

```
$('span.fa-caret-right').on('click',function(){
    // remove existing open class on li
    $('li').removeClass('open');
    // add class on current element(li)
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('open');
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/s5hyrjr6/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/464dzhno/4/

```
$('nav#nav li:has(ul)').toggleClass('open');
```

is replaced with

```
$(this).closest('li:has(ul)').toggleClass('open');
```

You need to toggle `open` class only for the li whose child is the span you are handling click for.

Answer (score 0):

Change your click function span.fa-caret-right to

```
$('span.fa-caret-right').on('click',function(){
  $('nav#nav li:has(ul)').removeClass('open');
  $(this).parent().addClass('open');
});
```